# Responsive adSense ads - dynamically reloading

Tags: javascript, mobile, dynamic, responsive-design, adsense

I have this code from labnol.org running on a responsive website (http://goo.gl/asEovC):

```
<div id="google-ads-1"></div>

<script type="text/javascript"> 

    ad = document.getElementById('google-ads-1');

    if (ad.getBoundingClientRect().width) {
        adWidth = ad.getBoundingClientRect().width; // for modern browsers 
    } else {
        adWidth = ad.offsetWidth; // for old IE 
    }

    /* Replace ca-pub-XXX with your AdSense Publisher ID */ 
    google_ad_client = "ca-pub-XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX";

    /* Replace XXXXXXXXXN with the AdSense Ad Slot ID */
    if ( adWidth >= 728 )
      google_ad_size = ["728", "90"],  /* Leaderboard 728x90 */
      google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXXX0";
    else if ( adWidth >= 468 )
      google_ad_size = ["468", "60"],  /* Banner (468 x 60) */
      google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXXX1";
    else if ( adWidth >= 336 )
      google_ad_size = ["336", "280"], /* Large Rectangle (336 x 280) */
      google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXXX2";
    else if ( adWidth >= 300 )
      google_ad_size = ["300", "250"], /* Medium Rectangle (300 x 250) */
      google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXXX3";
    else if ( adWidth >= 250 )
      google_ad_size = ["250", "250"], /* Square (250 x 250) */
      google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXXX4";
    else if ( adWidth >= 200 )
      google_ad_size = ["200", "200"], /* Small Square (200 x 200) */
      google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXXX5";
    else if ( adWidth >= 180 )
      google_ad_size = ["180", "150"], /* Small Rectangle (180 x 150) */
      google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXXX6";
    else
      google_ad_size = ["125", "125"], /* Button (125 x 125) */
      google_ad_slot = "XXXXXXXXX7";

    google_ad_width = google_ad_size[0];
    google_ad_height=google_ad_size[1];

</script>

<script src="http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js"></script>
```

The code above fails to address the resizing issue, if the browser is resized the ads will remain the same size and layout will break. This gets relevant in case of device orientation changes on tablets and smartphones. I am trying to find a solution for reloading the ads if/when the size (size-group) changes.

Comment: https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3543893?hl=en&ref_topic=3641113

Comment: Yes, I am testing google's new solution now, last time it wasn't suitable versus labnol's solution.

Comment: Google's proprietary solution, the Responsive ad, is almost the same as the code above, does not address the device orientation changes and layout break.

Answer (score 2):

Google has new responsive code which apparently can deal with layout changes after a screen orientation change:

https://support.google.com/adsense/answer/3213689?hl=en

> Support for ad size changes after a screen orientation change. If your responsive page changes its layout following a device orientation change (e.g., when a tablet or phone goes from portrait to landscape), we’ll request and load a new ad of the correct dimensions to fit the new page layout.
>
> Note:
>   When we load a new ad following a device orientation change, we cache the original ad that was shown. If the device then returns to its previous orientation, we’ll show the original ad again rather than load another new ad.
>   As the ad refresh behavior for screen orientation changes creates additional ad requests, you might notice a slight decrease in your RPM and CTR metrics. Please be assured though that there's no impact to your overall revenue.